# What is the full pep8 argument list for vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pep8

I am trying to configure my python environment in vscode, by overwriting a few of the default settings.

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--indent-size=2"
]
```

Currently whenever I format my python code, the following happens.

```
some_string = "this is a string"  # original
some_string="this is a string"    # formatted
```

I want to overwrite this option, and I am unaware of the argument name to do so.

I have been unable to find a complete list of arguments that I can pass to pep8 for overwrite. 
Reading [this](https://wingware.com/doc/edit/pep8) guide, I found out that I can overwrite the default pep8 configuration for spaces around the `=` sign. There seems to be an argument called `around spaces` and I am unaware of what it translates to in vscode.

Does anyone know of the `pep8/pycodestyle` full argument list?

Comment: "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds", see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @Peter that is the style guide. That does not help me. I am looking for the arguments list that I can use to overwrite default settings.

Comment: That was exactly my point.